# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model: How to retrieve subwebs for a specified user?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I have a need to retrieve a list of subwebs for a specified user using the client object model.  The challenge is that this is being called from a C# web service that is running under the identity of a SharePoint user with access to all the subwebs.  Is there a way to filter this list to only return those that belong to a specified user?  I only have the username and do not have the password for this account so direct impersonation using NetworkCredential is not going to work.

Pseudo code below:

```
 var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var site = clientContext.Web;
 var user = site.CurrentUser;
 clientContext.Load(site);
 clientContext.Load(user);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 var webCollection = site.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
 clientContext.Load(webCollection);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 foreach (var web in webCollection)
 {
      // should I check permissions here?
 }
```